# Resetting a project to have consistent spacing convention

Tags: formatting, spacing

We have had a new developer join our team and now found out they committed a whole bunch of files using a different spacing convention than the rest of the team.

How is the easiest way to update the whole project to use the same spacing convention?

(I use VS Code as a text editor if someone has an editor based approach)